# Difficulty importing a .crt self signed certificate in Windows 10

Tags: windows, ssl-certificate

I am trying to import a .crt certificate using the wizard in MMC. When I try to import it I receive the error "The file type is not recognisable. Select another file."

Opening the file in Notepad, it looks sensible to me. It begins with the header:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Then the key. Then:

```
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
```

Then the certificate. Then:

```
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Windows and multi-PEM files aren't really friends.  If you want to import the certificate with an associated private key you need to convert the key and cert to a PFX.

If you flipped and had the cert first then MMC would probably load the certificate, but just ignore the key.  Since the key was first it's probably reporting "weird, it's PEM, but not a certificate..."